# Ajax Json Image Parsing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api

I have this json file http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/images/apikey/demo/propertycode/zinc52/propertycode/proch
an im trying to pull an image from it using jquery/ajax and put it into a div. Im very new at this and just cant seem to do it.

Thanks for your help
This is an adapted code that i have tried to use but it returns nothing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://sunrise.bluechipholidays.co.uk/webservices/property/images/apikey/demo/propertycode/zinc52/propertycode/proch", {
        caption: "kitchen",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            var img = $("<img />");
            img.attr('width', '200px');
            img.attr('height', '150px');
            img.attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#dvImages");
            if (i == 5) return false; //5 is number returned
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to post what you've tried. That's a basic requirement of having a question on this site. Even if what you've already tried is embarassing and ridiculous, it helps us get an idea of what you already know and where to start.

Comment: hi brian, thanks for the tips it makes sense that i show you i agree, i am also very new to stackoverflow

Comment: I'm going to edit it for you, but SO supports code tagging so your code is more readable.

Comment: OK, after looking at the code, I need you to try something. Put an `alert()` in your function, before the `$.each`. This will tell us that you're definitely getting into the complete function. If you aren't, then something's wrong with the call. That's a definite possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get('<your_link_here>', function(data){
    var $yourDiv = $('#yourDiv');
    $(data.data).each(function(i, x){
        $(x).each(function(j, k){
            var $img = $('<img></img>');
            $img.attr('src', k.url)
            $yourDiv.append($img);
        });
    });
});
```

Should do the work, though I haven't test it yet. I assumed you use jquery 1.9.1 btw.

I edited your code and working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6FW3R/6/

my bad i edited the fiddle and the code itself here.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, ive tried it and it doesnt work  http://jsfiddle.net/garrycalliopix/6FW3R/3/  im probably doing something silly

Comment: hi thanks a lot for that, i have added a code on line 3 to just show the first result only. clearly im doing something wrong

Comment: I didn't understand if you are talking about, first image on entire json or images on the first data field on that json object. I think you better be looking at the structure of json on google chrome with [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) extension.

Comment: thats great thanks for the link and your help. one last think why on the fiddle does it not actually display the images and just the pic icon?

Comment: it's not just k variable, it must be k.url, then the picture comes.